# When using the Fetch API, is there a preferred way to send data via POST requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

I am using the Fetch API repeatedly in my project.  I am wondering if there are stylistic, speed reasons, etc... that I would want to consider when choosing a way to send data in a POST request.

For example, I could send data via the body or via a Headers object in the following case:

```
return fetch("url", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
            'description': 'true',
            'state': 'stateToken',
        })
    })....

return fetch("url", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'description': 'true',
            'state': 'stateToken',
        })
    })....
```

Is there a 'best' way to send the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is recommended to send data in the body rather than in the headers - headers are really to tell the server stuff about the data (e.g. what format, who the sender is, etc). Sending actual data in headers is a bit weird and could cause problems with caching.

Comment: Headers can also sometimes have more aggressive length constraints. In other words, a large payload might fail in a header but work in the body just because they have different maximum lengths..